# Angular connecting data from two controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a two calls,for match and matches. Match gets the data for one specific match, and matches the whole batch, with some relative ratings. I need to pass those relative ratings to a matching specific match.

Service that returns the json data from different API endpoints

```
function matchService($http, $q, API_URL) {

 function getMatchesForVacancy(vacancyId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get(API_URL + vacancyId + '/matches') //v2.0 lib
    .then(function matchesArrived(matchData) {
      deferred.resolve(matchData.data);
    }, function matchesFailed(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
 }

 function getMatchForVacancy(vacancyId, accountId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get(API_URL + vacancyId + '/matches/' + accountId)
    .then(function matchesArrived(matchData) {
      //matchData.data.candidateRating = {overallScore: 0.65}; - ie. what I need to get
      deferred.resolve(matchData.data);
    }, function matchesFailed(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
 }
```

Matches and match are displayed in the different views, so I have separate controller files. Now in the single match controller I am trying to pass in the specific rating where id's are the same.

So what I tried to do, was in candidate controller create a function like this:

```
function connectRating(vacancyId, match){
  var matches = matchService.getMatchesForVacancy(vacancyId);
  for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){

    if(matches[i].accountId === match.accountId){
      match.candidateRating.overralScore = matches[i].candidateRating.overralScore;
      return match;
    }  
  }
}
```

The json for matches is like this:

```
  [
   {
    "accountId": 0,
    "candidateRating": {
      "overallScore": 0
     }
   }
  ]
```

And somehow the right data is not passed, or anything for that matter. I must be missing something, so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the successful function of your promise. That's when you have a guarantee of the asynchronous result. Try this:

```
matchService.getMatchesForVacancy(vacancyId).then(function(d){
   // the return data is in "d"
   // do whatever you want with it
});
```